# Parameters required by bar3d with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a 3d bar plot with python, and I discovered the `bar3d` function. Here is the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d/).
I do not understand which values I have to pass over to `bar3d`, documentation only tells me something about the appropriate format. I have found a few example on the internet, and also on stackoverflow, but these didn't help me to figure out which parameter contains which information.

Basically, this is my function:

```
bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average', *args, **kwargs)
```

I do not understand what `x, y, z` and `dx, dy, dz` do represent. Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`x`, `y`, `z`, `dx`, `dy`, `dz` are iterators. They represent the `x` and `y`, `z` positions of each bar and `dx`, `dy`, `dz` represent the width, depth, and height (dimensions in `x`, `y` and `z`) of the bars. Note that `x` is the horizontal axis, `y` is the depth axis, and `z` is the vertical axis.

So 3 bars in a row with height of 5, 4 and 7 could be drawn like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]  # x coordinates of each bar
y = [0, 0, 0]  # y coordinates of each bar
z = [0, 0, 0]  # z coordinates of each bar
dx = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  # Width of each bar
dy = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  # Depth of each bar
dz = [5, 4, 7]        # Height of each bar
```

All of them would have the same width and depth.

`color` takes either a string that describes the color of all the bar, or a list of strings, if you want each bar with a different color.

I think `zsort` has to do with how matplotlib is handling overlaps, but that is just a guess.