# How to make 3D bar plot from dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

This is how my df looks like:

```
hr    slope  value   
8      s_1     6     
10     s_1     2     
8      s_2     4     
10     s_2     8
```

I would like to make a 3D bar plot with 'hr' in the x-axis, 'value' in the y-axis, and 'slopes' in the z-axis.

```
xpos = df['hr']
ypos = df['value']
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos=np.zeros(df.shape).flatten()

dx=0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy=0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dz=df.values.ravel()

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color='b', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error messages:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Any help is very welcome,
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `bar3d()` can be found at https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24737468/10315163) is an explanation of it. Official demo can be found at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xpos = [1, 2, 3]  # x coordinates of each bar
ypos = [0, 0, 0]  # y coordinates of each bar
zpos = [0, 0, 0]  # z coordinates of each bar
dx = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  # Width of each bar
dy = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  # Depth of each bar
dz = [5, 4, 7]        # Height of each bar

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz, color='b', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem why you got this error is that the length of `xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz` is not the same. Besides, the element of `dz` contains string.

Here is how I reproduce your example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')

xpos = df['hr']
ypos = df['value']

xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()

zpos = np.zeros(df.shape).flatten()

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dz = df[['hr', 'value']].values.ravel()

print(xpos)
print(ypos)
print(zpos)
print(dx)
print(dy)
print(dz) # [8 's_1' 6 10 's_1' 2 8 's_2' 4 10 's_2' 8]

print(len(xpos))  # 16
print(len(ypos))  # 16
print(len(zpos))  # 12
print(len(dx))    # 12
print(len(dy))    # 12
print(len(dz))    # 12

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color='b', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

The content of `1.csv` is

```
hr,slope,value
8,s_1,6
10,s_1,2
8,s_2,4
10,s_2,8
```