# Matplotlib 3D ValueError shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

x = np.arange(1,11)
y = np.array([5,6,7,8,2,5,6,3,7,2])
z = np.zeros(10)

dx = np.ones(10)
dy = np.ones(10)
dz = np.arange(1,100)

ax.bar3d(x,y,z,dx,dy,dz,color=np.array(['r','b','y','k','orange','lime','aqua','c','m','g']))
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
ax.set_title('3D Bar Chart')`

plt.show()
```

why do i get this error when i run this?

`Exception has occurred: ValueError shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (10,) and arg 5 with shape (99,).` 
i expect this code can run well and plot my diagram

Comment: It is because the parameter for `dz` is of shape 99. But there are only 10 bars to plot. It seems you are not quite sure what these arguments are used for. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24737468/14234692) answer to another question to get some insights.

Comment: ah thanks sir for your comment, i am typo here, i changed it to be dz = np.arange(1,11) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Marco pointed you in the right direction.

When you don't know what a parameter does, look at the documentation. In your case type `help(ax.bar3d)`, which will give you something like this:

```
Generate a 3D barplot.

This method creates three-dimensional barplot where the width,
depth, height, and color of the bars can all be uniquely set.

Parameters
----------
x, y, z : array-like
    The coordinates of the anchor point of the bars.

dx, dy, dz : float or array-like
    The width, depth, and height of the bars, respectively.
```

So, if you want to modify the size of each bar, `dx, dy, dz` should have the same number of elements of `x, y, z`.